# Brew won't run with released Xcode 11

Tags: homebrew

I installed the latest Xcode 11 release (11A420a) on Mojave 10.14.6 and now homebrew fails with

`Error: Xcode alone is not sufficient on Mojave.
Install the Command Line Tools:
  xcode-select --install`

The command line tools are installed

`$ xcode-select --install
xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates`

Any idea how to get past this?

Comment: Ah, it could be related to macOS Mojave 10.14.6 Supplemental Update 2

Comment: Did you perform the software update as the error told you? Make sure you use the sudo keyword in front of commands

Comment: There is nothing available in software update.

Answer (score 0):

Although your XCode is 11, your XCode Command Line tools are outdated. Upgrade the XCL according to the error message.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the system was confused about what was in `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools`. So I removed that version and did `xcode-select --install` and everything is happy again.